# fadetoggle 2 times how (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Jquery

```
<script> 
//Team
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".team").click(function(){
        $(".panel").fadeToggle("3000");
    });
    $(".team").click(function(){
        $(".teamh").fadeToggle("3000");
    });
}); 
</script>
```

HTML

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
//Team
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".team").click(function(){
        $(".panel").fadeToggle("3000");
    });
    $(".team").click(function(){
        $(".teamh").fadeToggle("3000");
    });
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<!--Buttons-->
<a><span class="team"></span></a>
<a><span class="events"></span></a>
<a><span class="media"></span></a>
<a><span class="contact"></span></a>
<span class="panel"></span>
<span class="teamh"></span>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <span class="panel"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Above you can see me trying to fade toggle a panel and while faded-in I want the "button" to hover in the html its an `<a>` tag.

So I´d like: While .team toggled to show panel and add my hover.

Comment: Please provide your HTML code as well.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot i will post it as a comment.

Comment: Better to edit your question than posting code in the comments.

Comment: ok done deleted the anwser added html in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want, but I have done this fiddle for you which will toggle the two panels:

```
 $(".team").click(function()
    {       
                $(".teamh").fadeToggle("3000",function()
                    {
                     $(".panel").fadeToggle("3000");                     
                    });
    }   );
```

Basically when you click your link, the teamh panel is toggled - one its toggle fade completed it will toggle the other panel.  Note one panel's display is set to be hidden

https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/rcy4vu8L/

It uses the fade 
toggle complete callback function then toggles the other panel.

If you simply want to toggle both panels then just call the fadeToggle in the same click handler:

```
 $(".team").click(function()
 {      
         $(".teamh").fadeToggle("3000");
         $(".panel").fadeToggle("3000");    
});
```

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/beeLqv6x/

Comment: Thanks a lot thats what I wanted.

Comment: I have another one to add id like it to close again class "teamh" is a hover i want that it closes again when you press on the hover.